# How to give access to s3 files to authenticated web site users

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-core

I have a .net core web app, when someone uploads a file to a post in the app, I store it in an s3 bucket. I don’t want the s3 bucket to be publicly accessible, I only want logged in users to be able to download files from it.

Is the recommended solution for this creating temporary links directly to the s3 files when they are requested through the site by authenticated users? I don’t want these links to be accessible later by non-authenticated users.

Or should I download the file to the web server then stream it to the user, in effect doubling my bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate the links from the .net backend which the client wont easily be able to copy and share. And they will expire after given time.

Try this from Amazon documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html